# Use software to remove clouds from imagery

Tags: windows, open-source, gis, image

Do you have a suggest for me to use a good software that will let me to remove clouds from an aerial photography ? They are in the 1938's

I work a lot of aerial photography but they are not orthorectified and are not overlap to each other. I want to do pre-process them first before I could use them in an Agisoft Metashape.

I know that ERDAS Imagine 2020 can do that ; but the problem is that it requires you to have two orthorectified overlap each other in order to remove the clouds.

Comment: Without overlapping images, how would the software know what lies below the clouds?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: could be some AI magic algorithm that imitates the material which surrounds the cloud. Adobe has it in their products for removing unwanted stuff.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, I it could definitely fill in the cloud-covered area with the surrounding terrain (no AI needed!).  But, for example, if there is an oasis with clouds over it in the middle of the desert, the entire oasis will disappear in the result.  Similar results would happen with a village in a jungle, or any other cloud-covered area that differs from its surroundings.  I think what we need to know is: PROBERT, are you good with solutions that would generate this type of result?

Comment: What kind of Adobe does that ? Not sure how but I'd like to give it a try even I have been looking around on the internet